# Como mostrar informacion de regreso en un textarea (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, textarea

Tengo un campo de tipo `textarea` en un formulario donde me encuentro realizando algunas pruebas y quisiera saber como puedo mostrar la información de regreso en un textarea, es decir al momento de editar el formulario respectivo, no me muestra esa información que tengo almacenada en el `textarea` de regreso, el siguiente es el formulario donde tengo el `textarea` con su función **Javascript** para actualizar

`updateService()` es el nombre de la función para actualizar, ya ves que al momento de actualizar el registro no me muestra la información que anteriormente registre en el `textarea`.

Explico un poco mejor, tengo un formulario de registro con muchos campos y dentro de esos campos tengo uno que es un `textarea`, al momento de modificar el registro uno espera que le traiga toda la información de regreso en los campos, pero el problema es que en el campo de `textarea` no me la trae de regreso.

```js
function updateService() {
    $("#submit").css("display", "none");
    $("#load").css("display", "block");

    const serviceDescription = document.getElementById("serviceDescription").value;


    $.ajax({
        url: document.getElementById("updateService").value,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {

            content: serviceDescription,

        },
        success: function(data) {
            $("#message").text("Se han guardado correctamente sus cambios.");
            $("#serviceResultModal").modal({
                backdrop: "static",
                keyboard: false
            });


            $("#submit").css("display", "block");
            $("#load").css("display", "none");
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Ocurrió un error, porfavor inténtalo de nuevo.");
            $("#submit").css("display", "block");
            $("#load").css("display", "none");
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="form-group">
                                <label class="required-field" name="descripcionServ" for="serviceDescription">Descripción:</label>
                                <div style="font-size:x-small; text-align: right;">
                                 <label id="charserviceDescrInput">250</label>/250
                                </div>
                                <textarea onchange="validateService(this)" id="serviceDescription" name="descripcionServ" class="form-control validateable" style="border-radius: 1rem;" rows="4" maxlength="250"></textarea>
                                   
                                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const serviceDescription = document.getElementById("serviceDescription");

$.ajax({
        url: document.getElementById("updateService").value,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {

            content: serviceDescription.value,

        },
        success: function(data) {
            $("#message").text("Se han guardado correctamente sus cambios.");
            $("#serviceResultModal").modal({
                backdrop: "static",
                keyboard: false
            });
            serviceDescription.value = data.valor_de_regreso;
            $("#submit").css("display", "block");
            $("#load").css("display", "none");
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Ocurrió un error, porfavor inténtalo de nuevo.");
            $("#submit").css("display", "block");
            $("#load").css("display", "none");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Mira [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para que puedas dar una buena respuesta, trata de explicar que es lo que estás haciendo y porqué lo haces de esa manera, la idea es aprender que es entender el código y no simplemente copiar y pegar.

Comment: Tu respuesta no me funciono aun no me trae el dato de regreso en el textarea, que pretendes que coloque en `data.valor_de_regreso;`

Comment: Explicame qué es lo que quieres traer de regreso en el textarea?

Comment: @JhonnatanYontonelSotelo La información que se registro, es decir, que al momento de modificar me muestro en el textarea lo que se registro inicialmente

Comment: @SebastianSalazar  Creo que lo entendí así: Lo que quieres es cargar un dato en el `<textarea>` y cuando lo modifiquen puedas validarlo y si la validación no es correcta volver a mostrar el dato que tenia anteriormente antes de ser modificado.

Comment: No es validacion de ese tipo, te lo pongo asi de sencillo, tengo un formulario de registro con muchos campos y dentro de esos campos tengo uno que es un `textarea`, al momento de modificar el registro uno espera que le traiga toda la información de regreso en los campos, pero el problema es que en el campo de `textarea` no me la trae de regreso

Comment: A ver... De donde se supone que te llegue el dato del `<textarea>`? del backend? esta en php o algún otro lenguaje? estas seguro que esta llegando el dato desde el backend? Si estas seguro entonces la solución que te puse arriba sería la correcta, teniendo en cuenta que `data.valor_de_regreso` es el valor de regreso desde el backend que se pintaría en el `<textarea>`